# starting rmiregistry wont work

Tags: java, implementation, rmi, distributed-system, rmiregistry

### got a problem with starting rmiregistry

When I enter start rmiregistry into the command line it returns an error:

---

java.rmi.RemoteException: failed to export: class gnu.java.rmi.dgc.DGCImpl
   at 0x00418dde (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004192d2 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00443aa4 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0046adc4 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040984d (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040989a (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00409090 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00468c70 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00468d37 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040906c (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040a972 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040ac05 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00401a80 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040cb73 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0040cbae (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00401733 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0047d601 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00416afe (Unknown Source)
   at 0x0041f220 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004033f7 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x004034c7 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00401328 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00401247 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x00401294 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x758fd305 (Unknown Source)
   at 0x770e15ff (Unknown Source)
   at 0x770e15d2 (Unknown Source)

---

I've seen a possible solution where you make sure your environment variables are pointing to the right jdk/jre, but i've done that and it should work.... but it doesnt.

The only other thing I can think of is that i'm on a university proxy.

Be good to hear your responses, Ta

Answer (score 0):

You have a thing called GNU CLASSPATH installed. It is not Java, it is a crippled and incompatible subset. Remove it and use a JDK or JRE.